SQLModel with FastAPI - use field for calculations, but hide it
Given the following model definitions for a simple budgeting API:
class BudgetBase(SQLModel):
    monthly_income: float
    name: str


class Budget(BudgetBase, table=True):
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint("name"),)
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str
    purchases: list[Purchase] = Relationship(back_populates="budget")


class BudgetPublic(BudgetBase):
    id: int


class BudgetPublicWithPurchases(BudgetPublic):
    purchases: list[PurchasePublic] = []


class BudgetCreate(BudgetBase):
    pass

I wish to retrieve different statistics for the purchases in the BudgetPublic class. An idea would be a @computed_field, like:
@computed_field
def total_spent(self) -> float:
    return sum(purchase.price for purchase in self.purchases)

However, this requires me to define a purchases field, which will be present on API responses of the BudgetPublic class. I wish to send the client the aggregated data, but not all the purchases themselves.
Is there any ways to achieve this?

Try this answer

Works perfectly, thanks!
